# React Native Bootstrap import issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to import bootstrap to my react native project. But this error is given. How can i solve this?

[My Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxvjr.png)

[Given error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYR8z.png)

Comment: Instead of sharing an image of your source code, please edit your post with your code in it.

Answer (score 1):

This package is available only for react for web, and not for react native.